# Pausing a CountDownTimer whilst another one runs - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer, pause

I have two countdown timers in my program, a longer one (120 sec) and a shorter one (3.5 sec). I want the 120 second timer to be paused whilst the 3.5 second timer is running, and for the longer timer to continue running whenever the 3.5 second timer isn't running. So the program starts with the 120 sec remaining whilst the 3.5 sec one runs, then when the 3.5 sec one runs the 120 sec one will start and only pause when the 3.5 sec one runs again (once users presses enter.) How would I do this?

```
final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(3500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                switch (keyCode) {
                                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                        Editable answer = input.getText();
                                        int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                        int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.getText()));
                                        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                            score++;
                                        }

                                        number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        if (score>=0 && score<=2){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(89999)+10000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        else if (score>=3 && score<=5){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(899999)+100000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        else if (score>=6 && score<=9){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(8999999)+1000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        else if (score>=10 && score<=14){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(89999999)+10000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        else if (score>=15 && score<=20){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(899999999)+100000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        else if (score>=21) {
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt((int) 8999999999L)+1000000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        input.getText().clear();

                                        start();

                                        return true;
                                    default:
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

            new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loop.cancel();
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();
```

I have asked this before, but was not given a valid answer unfortunately. Would be grateful if anyone is capable of answering this question. Please feel free to insert any code that'll help explain your answer. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you can ask this question a 100 times, but there is no method to pause a countdowntimer. You have to do a workaround and create a new timer when it will be needed. Now your question is  a duplicate of a duplicate....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No body gave me that answer before. What timer would need to be added? I'm happy to work around my issue, can you please post an explanation so I can mark this as resolved?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs By 'what timer' I mean a completely different one? Another copy of an existing timer? Etc...

Comment: It´s a little bit more complicated. I can give you a hint: You start your 120 seconds timer, anytime you decide to start the 3.5 second timer, then at the same time, stop the 120 second timer. Inside the 3.5 second timer, at finish, create the 120 second timer again and start it. I know it´s poor that countdowntimers have no pause method (i wish they have).....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Then doesn't that mean the 120 second timer starts from the beginning each time? Yeah, that's why I have asked here to see if anyone has a way around it. Thanks.

Comment: just make a global variable and calculate the remaining time and set the value of the variable to that one. Then use the variable for the new timer.

Comment: i tried it, look for my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will try to give an example, but no guarantee that this is exactly what you need:

create a global variable and the `CountDownTimer` objects:

```
Long remainingTime = 120000L;
ThreePointFiveSecondsTimer mThreePointFiveSecondsTimer;
HundredTwentySecondsTimer mHundredTwentySecondsTimer;
```

create the 120 seconds timer:

```
public class HundredTwentySecondsTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public HundredTwentySecondsTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }
```

create the 3.5 seconds timer:

```
  public class ThreePointFiveSecondsTimer extends CountDownTimer {

            public ThreePointFiveSecondsTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

              remainingTime = millisUntilFinished;//set the remaining time
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

//start the 120 second countdowntimer again
    mHundredTwentySecondsTimer  = new MyCountDownTimer(remainingTime, 1000);
    mHundredTwentySecondsTimer.start();
            }
        }
```

start the 120 second timer:

```
mHundredTwentySecondsTimer  = new MyCountDownTimer(remainingTime, 1000);
mHundredTwentySecondsTimer.start();
```

Then, at any time,  you decide to start the 3.5 timer:

```
mThreePointFiveSecondsTimer   = new ThreePointFiveSecondsTimer (3500, 1000);
mThreePointFiveSecondsTimer.start();
mHundredTwentySecondsTimer.cancel();
mHundredTwentySecondsTimer = null;
```

That´s just the idea behind, but you have to adjust this to your needs. Sorry, but can´t give you all the stuff you need, that will be beyond the frame.

Comment: I didn't actually read your post, as I had just resolved the issue before checking back on here. I returned to post briefly what I did to resolve the issue, but I'm marking your answer as the resolution due to your time and effort trying to help me out. Thanks for understanding, much appreciated.

Comment: :).... and it was the same solution...some kind of thought transfer.. it would be nice of you put a part of code in your answer how do you have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this (I have not tested but hope it will work)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private long remainingTimeForTimer = 0;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Start first timer
        test1(120 * 1000);

        // now on the basis of remaining timer you can cancel current timer and after that second timer you can start that timer with remaining time

        if(remainingTimeForTimer > 0)
        {
            test1(remainingTimeForTimer);
        }


    }



    private void test1(long totalTimerTime)
    {

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimerTime, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                remainingTimeForTimer = millisUntilFinished;

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {


                //trialCount = 0;

            }
        };

        mCountDownTimer.start();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

I have resolved this issue after trying multiple times. I ended up putting the larger timer in the onFinish of the shorter one and setting the initial time of that longer timer equal to millisUntilFinished. Then I cancel the long timer when the user presses enter and it automatically starts with the updated time whenever the EditText box is displayed.